# draw the scattered graph for every 10 seconds using Coreplot in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to draw the graph for every second like the [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007410-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example by apple . But only one change in drawing is I have to draw the graph based on x and y axis . I have tried using the Coreplot . It is showing the graph once we store the values in the array statically . But I have to draw dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside didAccelerate delegate you can update your array and call `[graph reloadData];` to update your coreplot graph. or if you want it to draw after every 10 seconds then call reloadData after 10 seconds delay.

Comment: @Tendulkar Calling [graph reloadData] will enforce the delegate methods to be called. So if you change the data you are storing in the graph and call reloadData, it should work.